# Power Automate/Logic Apps trigger On Post of Item Journal OR Edit of Inventory of Item table of Business Central

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate, dynamics-business-central

In Business Central, is it possible in PowerAutomate/LogicApp to have a trigger whenever any Item journal record get posted successfully. OR it would be fine if we have a trigger in PowerAutomate/LogicApp only if Inventory get updated on Item table. Is it possible? If not then Do we have any workaround to achieve the same?

Please help and guide us further.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know Business Central but do you have any ability to catch a trigger from your scenario (from within BC that is) and fire a web hook? ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/dynamics-subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default Business Central actions in Power Automate to achieve this

[image]

[image]